# Set required field value in lightning-file-upload

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components

In lightning-file-upload component in LWC, I am trying to set one **required** custom picklist field value on the content version.
For this, I have used the below code:

```
 <lightning-file-upload accept={acceptedFormats} 
                               label="Attach sites"                                   
                               onuploadfinished={handleUploadFinished} 
                               record-id={recordId}
                               file-field-name="Custom_field__c"
                               file-field-value={fieldValue}></lightning-file-upload>
```

Here I have set **file-field-name** and **file-field-value** values, but when the file is uploaded, I get the option to select the field value and after selecting the value(on click of Next), the file gets uploaded.[image]

If I make this field not required, then the file gets uploaded without selecting any option.
I am not using a guest user.

Documentation referred: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-file-upload/documentation

Answer (score 3):

### usage of file-field-name and file-field-value attributes in lightning-file-upload

To enable guest users to upload files to a record, the org admin can create a custom field on the ContentVersion object. The field type can be text or picklist. The API name of the custom field must end with **`fileupload__c`**. For example, you can use the API name **`Guest_Record_fileupload__c`** for the custom field.

Specify the **`file-field-name`** and **`file-field-value`** attributes in lightning-file-upload to store a value in the custom field in the ContentVersion object. For example, set file-field-name to **`Guest_Record_fileupload__c`**. Set **`file-field-value`** to a value that can be used in Apex to associate the file to the record.

### **Coming to your case**

You have defined both the **`record-id`** and **`file-field-name`** and **`file-field-value`** attributes in the lightning-file-upload.

You can omit the **`record-id`** attribute when specifying **`file-field-name`** and **`file-field-value`** attributes. However, if you provide the **`record-id`**, **`file-field-name`** and **`file-field-value`** attributes, the record ID is ignored if the uploading user is a guest user.

Note that if you do not provide the **`record-id`** or **`file-field-name`** and **`file-field-value attributes`**, the uploaded file is private to an authenticated user.

To make field required, You have these options:-

1. You can mark field as required
2. Write a trigger on ContentVersion object to throw an error if field is blank
3. Create a validation rule to throw an error if field is blank

Comment: I am using Salesforce user not Guest user, still will your approach work?

Comment: @Ajinkyasd While some of the information provided in this answer is relevant to enabling guest user file upload, the key piece of information for you is that the custom field name should end with `fileupload__c`. For SF users, you can specify the `record-id`, `file-field-name` and `file-field-value` in the HTML file, but ensure that you are providing correct value for `fieldValue` in the JS code and that the custom field name ends with `fileupload__c`. This will ensure the value is updated correctly. I had marked the custom field as not req & was able to work this out  in my dev org.

Comment: can we use file-field-name for authenticated user also? I tried but field didn't get any value.

Answer (score 3):

Special thanks to @arut for noting down the hack.

The custom field name should end with **fileupload__c** to make it work. After changing the field name and appending **fileupload__c** to it, uploaded files are updated with the value in file-field-value.

Thanks again.